# deleting multiple records from table in django with checkbox using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I am new to Django and
I'm trying to delete multiple leads from a table in my Django application and everything works fine except when i try to do the #select_all checkbox in **thead** of the table, i get an error such as this in the console:

*jquery-3.6.0.js:10109 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/leads/delete/ 500 (Internal Server Error)*

Here is my code...

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, reverse, redirect
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import LeadModelForm
from .models import Lead



class LeadCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Lead
    template_name = "leads/lead_create.html"
    form_class = LeadModelForm

    def get_success_url(self):
       return reverse("leads:lead-index")


class LeadUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
   model = Lead
   template_name = "leads/lead_update.html"
   form_class = LeadModelForm
    
   def get_success_url(self):
     messages.info(self.request, "Lead updated successfully.")
     return reverse("leads:lead-index")


class LeadIndexView(generic.ListView):
   queryset = Lead.objects.all()
   paginate_by = 25
   template_name = "leads/lead_index.html"


def lead_delete(request, pk):
    lead = Lead.objects.get(id=pk)
    lead.delete()
    return redirect("/leads")



class LeadView(generic.View):
    def get(self, request):
        allleads = Lead.objects.all()
        context = {
            'leads': allleads
        }
        return  render(request, "leads/lead_index.html", context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      if request.method=="POST":
        lead_ids=request.POST.getlist('id[]')
        for id in lead_ids:
            lead = Lead.objects.get(pk=id)
            lead.delete()
        return redirect("/leads")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import LeadCreateView, LeadUpdateView, lead_delete, LeadView, LeadIndexView


app_name = "leads"
urlpatterns =[
    path('', LeadIndexView.as_view(), name='lead-index'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', LeadUpdateView.as_view(), name='lead-update'),
    path('create/', LeadCreateView.as_view(), name='lead-create'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', lead_delete, name='lead-delete'),
    path('delete/', LeadView.as_view(), name='delete-multiple'),
]
```

**lead_index.html**

````
{% load tailwind_filters %}
{%block content%}
{{form.media}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
      {% block title %}
        leads
      {% endblock title %}
    </title>
</head>
<body><br><br>
    <div class="container container-fluid">
      <div class="page-header">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" type="submit" id="delete_btn">
      Delete Selected <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th><input name="site_select_all" value="1" id="select_all" type="checkbox"/></th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                <th scope="col">Mail</th>
                <th scope="col">Source</th>
                <th scope="col">Category</th>
                <th scope="col">User</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="section">
              {% csrf_token %}
                {% for lead in object_list %}
                <tr id="{{lead.id}}">
                <td>{{lead.id}}</td>
                <td data-th="Select"><input type="checkbox" name="sel" value="{{lead.id}}"></td>
                <td class="col-md-3"><a href="{% url 'leads:lead-update' lead.pk %}">{{ lead.name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{lead.phone}}</td>
                <td>{{lead.email}}</td>
                <td>{{lead.source}}</td>
                <td>{{lead.category}}</td>
                <td>{{lead.user}}</td>
                <td>
                  <a href="{% url 'leads:lead-delete' lead.pk %}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Lead?');">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="del">
                      <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                  </a>
                </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
           </table>
          <div>
     </div>
 </div>
<br>
</body>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#delete_btn').click(function(){
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete selected?"))
    var id = [];
    var csrf = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken] ').val();
    $(':checkbox:checked').map(function(i){
      id[i]=$(this).val()
    })
    if(id.length===0){
      alert("No leads selected!")
    }
    else{
      $.ajax({
        url:"delete/",
        method: "POST",
        data:{
          id,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken:csrf
        },
        success:function(response){
          for(var i=0; i < id.length; i++){
            $('tr#'+id[i]+'').css('background-color', '#ccc');
            $('tr#'+id[i]+'').fadeOut('slow');
          }
        }
      })
    }
  })
});
$("#select_all").click(function(){
        $("input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));

});
</script>
</html>
{%endblock content%}```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to include more details. When encountering an HTTP error 500 (literally an *internal server* error), also include any output of the Django application (there is likely some output in the console or in a log file because something went blatantly wrong). This is usually important information and will help us helping you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the comment Alexander, ok i do believe that the problem is when i try to delete all data from the table using the select all method. Otherwise everything goes smooth and i can delete as many leads as i want as long as i dont click the checkbox in the table head. My guess would be that the select all onclick function does not get the ids of other table rows. As for the log you mentioned in the network recording in the inspect section in my browser i get a Lead matching query dont exist.

Comment: First and foremost, please [edit], as I have stated above, your question -- *don't* include clarification details in comments! Second, I meant the output of your Django server app, not your browser console. 500 indicates that something went wrong on the *server side*, which can't be seen in the Browser's DevTools. Also, I'm not a Django expert but stumbled across your post and thus would request that you include all necessary details in the question for anyone with more expertise than me to help you.

Comment: Ah ok sorry i did get that wrong. Ok this is what i get on the server side:                                      
                                                                                                                                  File "/home/misen/Downloads/weecrm/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
leads.models.Lead.DoesNotExist: Lead matching query does not exist.
[21/Apr/2021 08:36:13] "POST /leads/delete/ HTTP/1.1" 500 86083

Comment: How about [edit]ing your question to include this detailed information needed to help you?